# Citing Reference in Latex

Tags: beamer, bibliographies

When I cite a reference in LaTeX/Beamer the right bracket is not turned blue.  Is there a reason why this has happened?

[image]

See the right bracket after 2004.

see below the code

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{natbib}
\usetheme{CambridgeUS}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\hypersetup{
    colorlinks=true,
    allcolors=blue
    }

\title{Piling Platform Design}
\author{ZA}
\date{\today}
\institute{ABC}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
    \titlepage
\end{frame}

\section{Two-Layer System}

\begin{frame}[t]{Bearing Capacity for Two-Layer System}
If the above calculated bearing capacity is less than the maximum ground pressure value for either Loading Case 1 or 2, then a piling platform should be provided.  Suitable material for constructing the platform would be granular material such as crushed sandstone, recycled gravel or crushed rock.  The platform can further be reinforced with a layer of geogrid.  The thickness of the platform will depend on the maximum ground pressure of the rig, the bearing capacity of the ground and the material properties of the platform.\\ 

\vspace{0.25cm}

Two-layer bearing capacity formula suggested by \cite{skinner2004working} can be used to determine the thickness of the piling platform.  Meyerhof  assumed that the footing will punch through the upper firm/dense layer into the bottom soft/loose layer. 
\end{frame}

\section{References}

\begin{frame}[t]{References}
    \bibliographystyle{agsm}
    \bibliography{references.bib}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Please show the code you employ to generate the citation call-out.

Comment: Hi Mico, I have inlcuded the code

Comment: The code you've now provided does *not* give rise to the screenshot you posted earlier. When I run your code -- first, I had to create a dummy bib entry as follows: `@misc{skinner2004working, author = "Skinner", title = "Working", year = 2004}` -- the citation call-out says "Skinner (2004)", *not* "(Skinner (2004))". Please clarify what it is we are supposed to be looking out for.

Comment: Please extend your code to a [minimal working example with bibliography (MWEB)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4407).